# Ruby - recovering from .find not finding anything

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, find

```
$array_hash = [
                {
                    first: "John",
                    last: "Smith",
                    role: "Boss"
                },
                {
                    first: "Jane",
                    last: "Doe",
                    role: "Worker"
                }]

def find_employees_role(name)
    name = name.split(" ")

    result = $array_hash.find do | e | 
        e[:first] == name[0] && e[:last] == name[1]  #line16
    end[:role]

    result ||= "Not available"  
end


find_employees_role("Joe Smith")  #line 22
find_employees_role("John Smith") #"Boss"



Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(repl):16:in `find_employees_role'
(repl):22:in `initialize'
```

Here's an array with hashes in it.

My goal is to write a method that allows me to pass a name like "John Smith" as an argument and get back that person's role whether it be "Boss" or "Worker."

If the name is not in the database, I want it to return "Not available."

I tried to write that in with my

> result ||= "Not available"

The code works as intended when the name I pass to the method actually exists, but if I try to pass a name that is not already there, it doesn't even do what I expect. Instead, it returns the error stated.

I believe the error comes from [0][:role] being called on something that is undefined, and therefore does not have those array methods available to it. However, I am not sure how to overcome this problem.

Feel free to criticize any other aspects of my code that does not pertain to the problem at hand. My ears are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to look up `[:role]` even if the `find` fails and returns `nil`.

Try splitting the find and the hash lookup into two statements, so you can check for nil first.

```
entry = hash.find do |e| ... end 
result = entry ? entry[:role] :  "not available"
```

Comment: In general, the `find do |e| ... end[key]` is just hard to read.  Save that kind of shortcut for code golf.